# synchronize threads across processes in windows universal apps

Tags: windows, synchronization, global, semaphore, universal

Why is the System.Security.AccessControl namespace not available for Windows Universal apps?

I'm trying to use a named EventWaitHandle (or, a named Semaphore) that is global to the OS instance, but to do this seems to require the constructor that uses an EventWaitHandleSecurity object to set explicit permissions for the handle.

My larger problem: I'm trying to signal a thread inside a Windows Universal app *from* a service on the same OS instance.

Is there a way to signal events, or signal threads, across processes to a Windows Universal app?

Alternatively, I could poll from inside the Windows Universal app, but that's inelegant, risky and inefficient.

Note that this is only for Debug builds (or, special testing builds) of the Windows Universal app.

Is there a type of Semaphore or other global-capable synchronization object that Windows Universal apps use?

Comment: I don't know, but as a workaround (in case nobody else knows either!) could you create the event in the service and open it from the Universal app rather than the other way around?  (You can use an event object in the same way regardless of which process created it.)  Or perhaps get the service to inject a handle to the event into the Universal app?

Comment: Good idea, but no dice :(

Comment: The EventWaitHandle with global scope works fine outside of the context of the Windows Universal App. I tried this, cross-process. Maybe it's an app setting... ? Is there a security restriction on the app I can change? Help please!